# Expresión de C++ glm a Java JOML

Tags: java, c++, java-8, opengl

Estoy tratando de pasar esta expresión en C++ glm :

```
glm::vec3 cameraPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraFront = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0, -1.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
float cameraSpeed = 5.0f;

cameraPos += glm::normalize(glm::cross(cameraFront, cameraUp)) * cameraSpeed;
```

a Java JOML, pero no termino de dar con la clave correcta:

```
Vector3f cameraPos = new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
Vector3f cameraFront = new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
Vector3f cameraUp = new Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
float cameraSpeed = 5.0f;

Vector3f n = new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
n.get(cameraFront.cross(cameraUp));
n.normalize();
            
cameraPos.x -= (n.x * cameraSpeed);
cameraPos.y -= (n.y * cameraSpeed);
cameraPos.z -= (n.z * cameraSpeed);
```

He probado de muchas maneras distintas con malos resultados, también he buscado por Google sin éxito.

¿Alguien sabe como sería la expresión correcta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la [documentación del método `get` de `Vector3f`](https://joml-ci.github.io/JOML/apidocs/org/joml/Vector3f.html#get(org.joml.Vector3f)), el argumento es un objeto `Vector3f` **destino**, es decir que la llamada `n.get(cameraFront.cross(cameraUp))` copia las valores de `n` al vector temporal retornado por el producto cruz, lo cual no tiene ningún efecto.

Lo que buscas es el método [cross(Vector3fc v, Vector3f dest)](https://joml-ci.github.io/JOML/apidocs/org/joml/Vector3f.html#cross(org.joml.Vector3fc,org.joml.Vector3f)), que computa el producto cruz entre `this` y `v`, almacenando el resultado en `dest`.

```java
Vector3f cameraPos = new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
Vector3f cameraFront = new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
Vector3f cameraUp = new Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
float cameraSpeed = 5.0f;

Vector3f n = new Vector3f();
cameraFront.cross(cameraUp, n);
n.normalize();
            
cameraPos.x -= (n.x * cameraSpeed);
cameraPos.y -= (n.y * cameraSpeed);
cameraPos.z -= (n.z * cameraSpeed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cada función u operador en glm parece tener su contraparte en JOML. ¿Por qué no los usas simplemente?

```
Vector3f cameraPos = new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
Vector3f cameraFront = new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
Vector3f cameraUp = new Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
float cameraSpeed = 5.0f;

// Puedes encadenar las funciones ya que todas devuelven un Vector3f.
Vector3f normalizedCross = cameraFront.cross(cameraUp).normalize();

// En Java no puedes sobrecargar operadores.
// Por lo tanto, el creador hizo la función add, mul y otras.
cameraSpeed.add(normalizedCross.mul(cameraSpeed));
```

No olvides revisar la documentación.

Comment: Si no me equivoco, estas dos expresiones dan el mimo resultado

1)
`cameraPos.sub((cameraFront.cross(cameraUp).normalize()).mul(cameraSpeed));`

2)
`Vector3f n = new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);`
`cameraFront.cross(cameraUp, n);`
 `n.normalize();`
            
`cameraPos.x -= (n.x * cameraSpeed);`
`cameraPos.y -= (n.y * cameraSpeed);`
`cameraPos.z -= (n.z * cameraSpeed);`

sin embargo, a la hora de usarlas con un KeyListener para manejar la cámara con el teclado, con la primera expresión la cámara se vuelve loca y con la segunda funciona perfectamente. ¿alguna idea?.

Comment: Esto es lo más simplivicado que he logrado: `Vector3f crossed =  new Vector3f();
            cameraFront.cross(cameraUp, crossed);
            cameraPos.sub((crossed.normalize()).mul(cameraSpeed));`

Comment: ¿Pero por qué restas? Si en el código de C++ no aparece ninguna resta.

Comment: Son 4 teclas, adelante, detras, izquierda y derecha .. y he puesto la tecla que resta

Comment: Puede que alguna de las variables no esté siendo reiniciada. Entonces al ejecutar reiteradamente el código, esté afectando al resultado anterior y por eso se "vuelve loco".